# Create an array of labels in C# to show up on Form1.cs

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, label

I want to create an array of 361 labels(i.e., label, label1, label2, etc..) and have them physical positioned and showing up on my Form1.cs [Design].

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Label[] board = new Label[361];

    for (int i = 1; i < 362; i++)
    {
        board[i] = new Label { Name = "label" + i, Height = 55, Width = 55, MinimumSize = new Size(55, 55), Text = "label " + i   };
    }

    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    foreach (var Label in board)
    {
        if (x >= 580)
        {
            x = 0;
            y = y + Label.Height + 55;
        }

        Label.Location = new Point(x, y);
        this.Controls.Add(Label);
        x += Label.Width;
    }
}
```

I get an error with the `text = "label" + 1`. Not sure why. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Would you mind to provide exact error message?

Comment: there's not a syntax error, you'll have to be more specific

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in GomokuProject.exe

Additional information: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: The code above will throw an IndexOutOfRange error, change the value 362 to 361

Comment: Yes that worked! thank you. Now I get an error at label.location - new point...    An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in GomokuProject.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays are 0-indexed in C#, your last loop iteration will go over the max index.

```
Label[] board = new Label[361];
```

this creates an array of `Label` with indexes 0 - 360.  Simply alter your `for loop to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 361; i++)
```

this will also fix your `NullReferenceException`, which you were seeing because the first item in the array was never initialized

Comment: I didn't even see that he had 1 as the starting value. Good pickup

Answer (score 0):

Change the for loop from

```
        Label[] board = new Label[361];

        for (int i = 1; i < 362; i++) {
            board[i] = new Label { Name = "label" + i, Height = 55, Width = 55, MinimumSize = new Size(55, 55), Text = "label " + i };
        }
```

To

```
        Label[] board = new Label[361];

        for (int i = 0; i < 361; i++) {
            board[i] = new Label { Name = "label" + i, Height = 55, Width = 55, MinimumSize = new Size(55, 55), Text = "label " + i };
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

your board array is of size 361, So max would be board[360]

in your for loop i<362.. which means it will try to get value for board[360

Answer (score 0):

I modified the value of int in the loop, is this what you want?

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 361; i++)
        {
            board[i] = new Label { Name = "label" + i, Height = 55, Width = 55, MinimumSize = new Size(55, 55), Text = "label " + i };
        }

        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;

        foreach (var Label in board)
        {
            if (x >= 580)
            {
                x = 0;
                y = y + Label.Height + 55;
            }

            Label.Location = new Point(x, y);
            this.Controls.Add(Label);
            x += Label.Width;
        }
```